# Cron Job Parameters REST API

Tags: rest, web-services, cron, restful-architecture, apache-zeppelin

I'm just looking to submit a cron job using the Apache Zeppelin RESTful API.  The question is probably pertaining to submitting RESTful API calls of any kind though.

I'm looking to submit a POST request with JSON that sets cron job parameters.  There is the capability to submit cron job, but there is no help with specific format of how.

Two things...

1.) Is there usually an API doc stored somewhere, that the RESTFul API devs would store somewhere, that would be a common practice location for this type of document?

2.) I'm looking to submit a cron job that runs a given notebook [noteId] once a day.  I want the service to parse my JSON correctly. Do my assumptions for the JSON request make sense? Any help would be appreciated.

```
POST http://[zeppelin-server]:[zeppelin-port]/api/notebook/job/[noteId] HTTP/1.1
HOST: http://[zeppelin-server]
Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json 

{
  "credentials": {
    "name": "myZeppelinUserID",
    "password": "passw0rd"
     },
    "parameters": "0 0 * * *",
}
```

https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#add-cron-job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the credentials aren't needed, I can just use the curl command and send the POST message in a UNIX script.

```
curl  --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST  http://127.0.0.1:9995/api/notebook/job/2D2A6B5A8/
```